# Added column to existing dataframe but entered all numbers as NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I created two dataframes from existing CSV files, both consisting of entirely numbers. The second dataframe consists of an index from 0 to 8783 and one column of numbers and I want to add it on as a new column to the first dataframe which has an index consisting of a month, day and hour. I tried using append, merge and concat and none worked and then tried simply using:

```
x1GBaverage['Power'] = x2_cut
```

where x1GBaverage is the first dataframe and x2_cut is the second. When I did this it added x2_cut on properly but all the values were entered as NaN instead of the numerical values that they should be. How should I be approaching this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're the same row counts and you just want to tack it on the end, the indexes either need to match, or you need to just pass the underlying values. In the example below, columns 3 and 5 are the index matching & value versions, and 4 is what you're running into now:

```
In [58]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3,3)))

In [59]: df
Out[59]:
          0         1         2
0  0.670812  0.500688  0.136661
1  0.185841  0.239175  0.542369
2  0.351280  0.451193  0.436108

In [61]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3,1)))

In [62]: df2
Out[62]:
          0
0  0.638216
1  0.477159
2  0.205981

In [64]: df[3] = df2

In [66]: df.index = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [68]: df[4] = df2

In [70]: df[5] = df2.values

In [71]: df
Out[71]:
          0         1         2         3   4         5
a  0.670812  0.500688  0.136661  0.638216 NaN  0.638216
b  0.185841  0.239175  0.542369  0.477159 NaN  0.477159
c  0.351280  0.451193  0.436108  0.205981 NaN  0.205981
```

If the row counts differ, you'll need to use `df.merge` and let it know which columns it should be using to join the two frames.

Comment: Ok so I tried that and it added it on but it didn't seem to use the index of the first one. I'm new to stack overflow, so how can I post the code in that format so I can show you what it looks like? I'm using iPython if that makes a difference. If there's no way to do that I'll try to explain what happened. Pretty much, it appeared to add the new column at the very bottom in the form of an array, so once I printed out the dataframe, it looked the same as the original except at the bottom it has the name of the new column, power, followed by [-47, -46, -46...] which are the values

Comment: If you paste your code, highlight it, and click the {} button, it will indent it all 4 spaces and then come out looking nice. For comments or inline code, you can include text in between backticks `like this`.

Comment: Alright I got it to work. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

x1GBaverage['Power'] = x2_cut.values

problem solved :)

The thing about pandas is that values are implicitly linked to their indices unless you deliberately specify that you only need the values to be transferred over.